# Get url parameter value of a page without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have nested records on a page and each has a url pointing to a page with url parameter. onclick of any of the record, i want to get the value of the url parameter in an alert without page refreshing

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click').on('click', function(event) {
        var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
        alert(url)
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a class="click" href="#?news_id=89">NEWS1</a> </p>
    <p><a class="click" href="#?news_id=90">NEWS 2</a>
```

Comment: The purpose of `href` attribute isn't to handle some data. You'd have better to modify HTML markup (if you are rendering it in first place) to add some `data-*` attribute, e.g: `data-id="89"`

Comment: And if you remove the `href` attribute completely, add `tabindex="0"` to make sure that `<a>` is keyboard accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See comments inline in the code:

You can use `return false` or [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop page redirection.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click').on('click', function (event) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Get the `href` value of the clicked anchor
        var paramValue = href.split('=')[1]; // Get the value after =
        alert(paramValue);

        return false; // Stop redirection
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dtetrfto/)

Answer (score 2):

Return false at the end of the function to prevent page refresh

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(event) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href').match(/[0-9]+$/)[0];
  alert(url);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="click" href="#?news_id=89">NEWS 1</a> 
<a class="click" href="#?news_id=90">NEWS 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided solutions so I'll try provide an explanation as to why `return false` inside the event handler solves the problem.

Your issue here is the actual action of clicking on an `<a>` tag. Clicking on an anchor tag will redirect you to the URL or anchor within the page you are on. Even with your event handler, the click event will sill make it's way up to the event handler that deals with redirecting the user to the specified `href` attribute on the tag.

Using `return false` prevents the event from continuing on it's path to other handlers.

---

Another similar solution would be to actually deal with the event itself inside the handler and [prevent it's default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```
$('.click').on('click', function (event) {
    ...
    event.preventDefault();  
)};
```

This won't stop the propagation of the event, but it will attempt to cancel it [if possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable).

Comment: To further explain what happens behind the scenes, returning `false` in a jQuery event handler will trigger `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `split()`:

```
var url = window.location.search.split('=').pop(); //works if its the only 1 parameter.
```

Or `match()`:

```
var url = window.location.search.match(/news_id=(\d*)/)[1]; // works even with mutilple parameters
```

As suggested by others, use `return false` to avoid page refresh.

```
$('.click').on('click', function(event) {
   // 
   return false;
});
```